# Netezza DB Query History

Tags: netezza

I would like to retrieve all the Netezza queries which was executed in database.In the Netezza GUI, I can able to retrieve only the active queries not the historic one.

I have googled that and nz_query_history database will help us to retrieve the information. But I don't know where to find this system database.

Please help me to find a solution for this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (free) tool that enables query history collection. At our site it’s called HISTDB, and it consists of several tables that is being fed by a process that is ‘near realtime’

See here: [link to manual on IBM site](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/c_adm_plg_overview.html)